# Shibboleth: "Metadata root element was unsigned and signatures are required"

Tags: shibboleth, samltest.id

I set up a Shibboleth IdP and I am testing it with samltest.id

Everything works fine if i do not enable signature verification. If I uncomment the relevant lines in my metadata-providers.xml the IdP won't start. The message is:

> ERROR [org.opensaml.saml.metadata.resolver.impl.AbstractReloadingMetadataResolver:537] - Metadata Resolver FileBackedHTTPMetadataResolver SAMLtest: Error filtering metadata from https://samltest.id/saml/sp
> org.opensaml.saml.metadata.resolver.filter.FilterException: Metadata root element was unsigned and signatures are required.

my metadata_provider.xml looks like this:

```
<MetadataProvider id="ShibbolethMetadata" xsi:type="ChainingMetadataProvider"
    xmlns="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:metadata"
    xmlns:resource="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:resource"
    xmlns:security="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:security"
    xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:metadata http://shibboleth.net/schema/idp/shibboleth-metadata.xsd
                        urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:resource http://shibboleth.net/schema/idp/shibboleth-resource.xsd
                        urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:security http://shibboleth.net/schema/idp/shibboleth-security.xsd
                        urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-schema-metadata-2.0.xsd">
    <MetadataProvider id="SAMLtest"
        xsi:type="FileBackedHTTPMetadataProvider"
        backingFile="%{idp.home}/metadata/SAMLtest.xml"
        metadataURL="https://samltest.id/saml/sp">
      <!-- You should always check the signature and freshness of remote
              metadata.  It's commented out until you get the basics working.-->
           <MetadataFilter xsi:type="SignatureValidation"
                  certificateFile="%{idp.home}/credentials/signet.crt" />
           <MetadataFilter xsi:type="RequiredValidUntil" maxValidityInterval="P30D"/>
   </MetadataProvider>
</MetadataProvider>
```

I'm using the latest version of Shibboleth 3.

I suspect this is something trivial, but I cannot figure it out. Is it that samltest.id does not sign their metadata and so SignatureValidation cannot be enabled? Why did they write that it should be enabled then?

Answer (score 1):

If you want test your IDP my first approach to this problem is to comment `MetadataFilter` tags so your metadata provider service (`MetadataResolverService`) can import metadata from  https://samltest.id/saml/sp.

You can call metadata provider service (`MetadataResolverService`) manually.

> bash /opt/shibboleth-idp/bin/reload-service.sh -id shibboleth.MetadataResolverService

Another reason for the problem may be that you do not add the samltest certificate to the IDP. As you indicated in your metadata_provider.xml, your IDP expect signet.crt file in credentials directory.

> certificateFile="%{idp.home}/credentials/signet.crt"

You can find certificate on the link below. You should create a signet.crt file with `Encryption Certificate` value.

- https://samltest.id/download/